# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useCallback') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useCallback')

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, react-hooks

People, I hope you can help me. I'm just getting into this world of programming, and there are still some things I don't fully understand and I'm getting a lot of errors. Can anyone help me with this error I'm getting and how I can fix it? I'm using React.js and ASP.Net Core 6. What I'm trying to do is that, when I log in, it redirects me to another page, which it does but only for a short period of time, after that I get the message "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useCallback') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useCallback')" and I can't figure out why.

My login code looks something like this:

```
function Login() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        (async () => {
            const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7100/api/Cars/AllCars');
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json);
        })();

    }, []);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7100/api/Cars/AllCars');
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json);
        }catch (error){
            console.log('Error en la solicitud', error);
        }
    }

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const API_URL = 'https://localhost:7100/api/Usuarios/inicioSesion';
  
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
      usuario: '',
      pass: '',
    });
  
    const handleChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setForm({
        ...form,
        [name]: value,
      });
    };

    const iniciarSesion = async (usuario, pass) => {
      try {
        // Realizar la lógica de inicio de sesión

        // Esperar confirmación del usuario
        const confirmacion = window.confirm('Bienvenido: ' + form.usuario);
  
        if (confirmacion) {

          navigate('/Menu');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
  
    return (
      <div className='principalContainer'>
        <div className='loginContainer'>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Usuario: </label>
            <br />
            <input type='text' className='form-control' name='usuario' onChange={handleChange} />
            <br />
            <label>Contraseña: </label>
            <br />
            <input type='password' className='form-control' name='pass' onChange={handleChange} />
            <br />
            <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => iniciarSesion(form.usuario, form.pass)}>
              Iniciar sesión
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Login;
```

The page I redirect to is a table where I have several vehicles in my database (using APIs I get the data), and it looks something like this:

```
function Menu() {
    const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState([]);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(null);
    const location = useLocation();

    const APi_URL = 'https://localhost:7100/';
  
  
    const showVehicles = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(APi_URL + "api/Cars/AllCars");
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setVehicles(data);
  
          // Guardar datos en localStorage
          localStorage.setItem('datosVehiculos', JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
          console.log('Error al obtener los datos');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error en la solicitud para obtener datos de vehículos', error);
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      showVehicles();
    }, []);
  
    const saveCar = async (car) => {
      const response = await fetch(APi_URL + 'api/Cars/NewCar', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(car),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        setShowModal(!showModal);
        showVehicles();
      } else {
        console.log('Error al obtener los datos');
      }
    };
  
    const editCar = async (car) => {
      const response = await fetch(APi_URL + 'api/Cars/EditCar', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(car),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        setShowModal(!showModal);
        showVehicles();
      } else {
        console.log('Error al obtener los datos');
      }
    };
  
    const deleteCar = async (id) => {
      var option = window.confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el vehículo?');
      if (!option) {
        return;
      }
      const response = await fetch(APi_URL + 'api/Cars/DeleteCar?id=' + id, {
        method: 'DELETE',
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        setShowModal(!showModal);
        showVehicles();
      } else {
        console.log('Error al obtener los datos');
      }
    };
  
    // Accede a los datos de vehículos desde location.state
    const datosVehiculos = location.state ? location.state.datosVehiculos: null;
  
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row className='mt-5'>
          <Col sm='12'>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <h1>Consulta de vehículos</h1>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Button size='sm' color='success' onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}>
                  Nuevo Vehículo
                </Button>
                <hr></hr>
                <CarsTable data={datosVehiculos || vehicles} setEdit={setEdit} showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} deleteCar={deleteCar} />
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <CarsModal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} saveCar={saveCar} edit={edit} setEdit={setEdit} editCar={editCar} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
  
  export default Menu;
```

It is worth mentioning that when I remove line 205 "CarsTable", I can make the redirection to the page without any error. The code for "carsTable" is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Table, Button } from "reactstrap";

const CarsTable = ({data, setEdit, showModal, setShowModal, deleteCar}) => {

    const sendData = (car) => {
        setEdit(car);
        setShowModal(!showModal);
    }

    return (
        <Table striped bordered responsive>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Marca</th>
                    <th>Modelo</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Año</th>
                    <th>Puertas</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    (data.length < 1) ? (
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="6">No hay vehículos registrados</td>
                        </tr>
                    ): (
                        data.map(vehicle => (
                            <tr key={vehicle.Id}>
                                <td>{vehicle.Id}</td>
                                <td>{vehicle.Make}</td>
                                <td>{vehicle.Model}</td>
                                <td>{vehicle.Color}</td>
                                <td>{vehicle.Year}</td>
                                <td>{vehicle.Doors}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button color="btn btn-warning" size="sm" className="me-2" onClick={() => sendData(vehicle)}>Editar</Button>
                                    <Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={() => deleteCar(vehicle.Id)}>Eliminar</Button>
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        ))
                    )
                }
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    )
}

export default CarsTable;
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me with the reason for this error, and if you could also help me with a solution. This code is only for learning. Greetings.

I'm trying to make it so that, when redirecting to my other page, I can load the data from my database through my API.